# Install xgboost on Mac - ld: library not found

Tags: xcode, macos, makefile, clang, xgboost

I am trying to install OpenMP enabled xgboost on my mac. I installed `gcc` with no problem:

```
brew install gcc --without-multilib
```

then cloned git repository:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost; cp make/config.mk ./config.mk
```

but I get an error when I do

```
make -j4
```

Here is the error I get. I'd appreciate if you can help fixing this problem:

```
c++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -o xgboost  build/cli_main.o build/learner.o build/logging.o build/c_api/c_api.o build/c_api/c_api_error.o build/common/common.o build/data/data.o build/data/simple_csr_source.o build/data/simple_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_raw_format.o build/data/sparse_page_source.o build/data/sparse_page_writer.o build/gbm/gblinear.o build/gbm/gbm.o build/gbm/gbtree.o build/metric/elementwise_metric.o build/metric/metric.o build/metric/multiclass_metric.o build/metric/rank_metric.o build/objective/multiclass_obj.o build/objective/objective.o build/objective/rank_obj.o build/objective/regression_obj.o build/tree/tree_model.o build/tree/tree_updater.o build/tree/updater_colmaker.o build/tree/updater_histmaker.o build/tree/updater_prune.o build/tree/updater_refresh.o build/tree/updater_skmaker.o build/tree/updater_sync.o dmlc-core/libdmlc.a rabit/lib/librabit.a  -pthread -lm  -fopenmp 
c++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -msse2  -Wno-unknown-pragmas -funroll-loops -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -fPIC -fopenmp -shared -o lib/libxgboost.so build/learner.o build/logging.o build/c_api/c_api.o build/c_api/c_api_error.o build/common/common.o build/data/data.o build/data/simple_csr_source.o build/data/simple_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_raw_format.o build/data/sparse_page_source.o build/data/sparse_page_writer.o build/gbm/gblinear.o build/gbm/gbm.o build/gbm/gbtree.o build/metric/elementwise_metric.o build/metric/metric.o build/metric/multiclass_metric.o build/metric/rank_metric.o build/objective/multiclass_obj.o build/objective/objective.o build/objective/rank_obj.o build/objective/regression_obj.o build/tree/tree_model.o build/tree/tree_updater.o build/tree/updater_colmaker.o build/tree/updater_histmaker.o build/tree/updater_prune.o build/tree/updater_refresh.o build/tree/updater_skmaker.o build/tree/updater_sync.o dmlc-core/libdmlc.a rabit/lib/librabit.a -pthread -lm  -fopenmp 
clangclang: : warningwarning: : argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'

ld: library not found for -lgomp
ld: library not found for -lgomp
clang: error: clanglinker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation): 
error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [lib/libxgboost.so] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [xgboost] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue and solved it by:

```
brew install clang-omp
export CC=clang-omp
export CXX=clang-omp++
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost; cp make/config.mk ./config.mk; make -j4
cd python-package
sudo python setup.py install
```

If you used pip to install xgboost before, then delete the previous installed xgboost from your project. Then use

```
pip install xgboost
```

to install it again.

Comment: clang-omp has been moved to the boneyard and is no longer available in brew. (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/commit/c57e307172d588046e7319cb2bb12ba1afc31a1d)

Answer (score 1):

A new versions of OSX has a Clang as a default c\c++ compiler. Therefore your `c++` command refers to `clang++`.

You should define a CC\CXX environmental variables for your make command like this `CC=gcc CXX=g++ make -j`

Also you can build an OpenMP for clang [OpenMPrt](https://www.openmprtl.org/download#stable-releases) and customise your shell environment (I didn't try this by own)

(I have no mac at this moment to check this solution; just linux)