# ld: library not found for -lomp

Tags: machine-learning, llvm, xgboost

In macOS Sierra, installation for xgboost with openmp enabled always fails.

From `https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build.html`,

I've tried:

> cp make/config.mk ./config.mk; make -j4

With,

```
export CC=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/4.0.0_1/bin/clang
export CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/4.0.0_1/bin/clang++
export CXX1X=/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/4.0.0_1/bin/clang++
```

It fails with,

```
clang-4.0clang-4.0: : warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]warning:
argument unused during compilation: '-pthread' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
ld: library not found for -lomp
ld: library not found for -lomp
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

llvm support openmp, but it fails with `ld: library not found for -lomp`

related question
[Install xgboost on Mac - ld: library not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038836/install-xgboost-on-mac-ld-library-not-found?rq=1)

But, clang-omp goes to boneyard, and discontinue with llvm's OpenMP support.

I've drilled down to, (with `-v` option)

```
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/4.0.0_1/bin/clang++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Iinclude   -Idmlc-core/include -Irabit/include -I/include -O3 -funroll-loops -msse2 -fPIC -fopenmp -shared -o lib/libxgboost.so build/learner.o build/logging.o build/c_api/c_api.o build/c_api/c_api_error.o build/common/common.o build/common/hist_util.o build/data/data.o build/data/simple_csr_source.o build/data/simple_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_dmatrix.o build/data/sparse_page_raw_format.o build/data/sparse_page_source.o build/data/sparse_page_writer.o build/gbm/gblinear.o build/gbm/gbm.o build/gbm/gbtree.o build/metric/elementwise_metric.o build/metric/metric.o build/metric/multiclass_metric.o build/metric/rank_metric.o build/objective/multiclass_obj.o build/objective/objective.o build/objective/rank_obj.o build/objective/regression_obj.o build/tree/tree_model.o build/tree/tree_updater.o build/tree/updater_colmaker.o build/tree/updater_fast_hist.o build/tree/updater_histmaker.o build/tree/updater_prune.o build/tree/updater_refresh.o build/tree/updater_skmaker.o build/tree/updater_sync.o dmlc-core/libdmlc.a rabit/lib/librabit.a -pthread -lm  -fopenmp
```

Answer (score 14):

**SOLVED**

```
cd /usr/local/lib
ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/4.0.0_1/lib/libomp.dylib libomp.dylib
```

llvm installation miss its symbolic link.

Comment: I think this might be needed in clang6 as well although I was using the clang6 from https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/ in High Sierra and getting failure to compile rJava 0.9-10 with an error about a missing libomp.

Answer (score 5):

In my case I solved adding the following linker flag in addition to -lomp:

-Lpath_to_libomp.dylib_folder

or something like:

-Llib/

Comment: Actually, llvm has `libomp.dylib` in its `lib` folder, but for some reason is does not work.
  
So yeah, for my setup `-L/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/ -fopenmp` fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used a version of `clang` that came with Homebrew's `llvm` instead of the one that came with the Laptop from the factory, and it worked.