# Installing rJava - ld: library not found for -lomp clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: r, rjava

I've been trying to troubleshoot installation of rJava in R (3.4.2) on my Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6. I've followed the advice I've found about OpenMP issues (http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/openmp-in-r-on-os-x/). The error I'm getting now, though, identifies the library not found as '-lomp' instead of '-fopenmp.' I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Here's what it looks like when it hits the error:

```
ld: library not found for -lomp
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libjri.jnilib] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/JRI.jar] Error 2
make: *** [jri] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/library/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/y_/0bm1vdx95dn4m8x_xtctp2gh0000gn/T/RtmpfslTnc/downloaded_packages’
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and fixed it by creating a link to the library (`libomp.dylib`) in a directory where it can be found (`/usr/local/lib/`), as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46141428/9085825).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here for full description of how to compile most recent Java inside OSX.

Note that you need clang with omp support - it is not available directly from Apple: http://www.owsiak.org/r-3-4-rjava-macos-and-even-more-mess/

You need to:

- get clang from llvm page
- configure R to use JDK of your choice
- compile rJava from sources